# Android Studio's auto-suggestion not working in XML editor

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android studio XML I tried to type in `TextView` but its not automatically suggesting and autocompleting it for me. Could any one please help me with this?

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/bVao4.png]

Comment: Please add your screenshot

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will allow others to quickly understand your problem and help you.

Comment: actually i uploaded it's not displaying

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVao4.png

Comment: please refer this link @PaoloColombo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This. From Menu `File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: Thank you this works. May I know what is the reason..??

Comment: Caches get outdated, they need to be cleared and refreshed sometimes. If this answer helped you, you should upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Sometimes android studio can't resolve the libraries included properly due to many scenarios( like internal conflicts etc). When you delete and rebuilt all the caches, it newly builds the caches, references again. So it works fine. Accept the answer as it solves the problem :)